# How to make Views iterating on data objects (without ListView / RecyclerView)?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to spawn some XML view for each instance of POJO data objects in a list, similar to how a ListView would do it, but it's not a `ListView` actually, but an empty LinearLayout instead, which is inside a `ScrollView` below other `Fragment`'s content.

#### This is the `item.xml` file I want to inflate for each element of the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="ITEM_LABEL"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="ITEM_TEXT_1"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="ITEM_TEXT_2"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### ...and this is the way I am trying to inflate it in the `Fragment` Java class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    // we skip the "boilerplate"...
    // [...]
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

       // XXX  I use LiveData<> with Room to retrieve
       //     rows from DB inside POJO objects
       LiveData<List<MyItem>> items_list = itemsViewModel.getItemsByParentId(some_id);
       //  The "parent" is not relevant, let's just
       // focus on the List
       LinearLayout items_list_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.items_list_layout);

       items_list.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<MyItem>>() {
           @Override
           public void onChanged(List<MyItem> items) {
               // Just in case, (maybe I'm wrong but) I think otherwise
               // previous inflated objects remain on loading this same
               // fragment for another parent
               objs_list_layout.removeAllViews()
               for (MyItem item : items) {
                   // XXX Here I inflate item.xml as a LinearLayout
                   LinearLayout obj_item = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(view.getContext(), R.layout.item, items_list_layout);
                   // XXX ... and try to change it's TextView children
                   TextView item_label = obj_item.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
                   item_label.setText(item.item_label);
                   TextView item_text1 = obj_item.findViewById(R.id.item_text1);
                   item_text1.setText(item.item_text1);
                   TextView item_text2 = obj_item.findViewById(R.id.item_text2);
                   item_text2.setText(item.item_text2);
               }
           }
       });
    }
}
```

This works well when the method `getItemsByParentId` only return a `List` with one only `MyItem` instance. But when the query returns more than one Item, it works unexpectedly wrong:

- The first inflated `item.xml` element (or the one shown first, on top) has its `TextViews` modificated as expected, but for the last item in the list.
- The rest of "inflated elements" have not been changed (it shows just ITEM_LABEL, ITEM_TEXT1 and ITEM_TEXT2 hardcoded strings as they are in the template XML file).
- However, it inflates the XML template `items.size()` times as I planned.

Actually, the objective is that each "inflated `item.xml`" is edited with attributes of each corresponding Item. Just like a ListView would do, but without using ListView at all, because the goal is, actually, bloating an existing `ScrollView` (the main container in the fragment) that shows other different Views outside of the "LinearLayout" dedicated to generate this "list". How can I make it work without these errors?

Comment: It sounds like you're making your life a lot more difficult than if you just used a single `RecyclerView` for your whole Fragment (using [RecyclerView's support for headers and footers](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) for your other layouts that need to go above and below your items).

Comment: That `View.inflate()` call is actually returning `items_list_layout`, not just the inflated item `View`, so the `obj_item.findViewById()` calls are always finding the first item's `View`s.

Comment: I am aware of the use of ListViews / RecyclerViews (well, RecyclerViews not so; my app uses ListViews; someday maybe I refactor to RecyclerView, but that's a different story)... but ListViews don't "expand it's size" inside the container layout, but create an scroll within their fixed size. Due to the container Layout is inside a ScrollView, using ListView / RecyclerView would make an scroll inside another scroll, which actually I don't want.

Comment: @Mike M. Somehow, my intuition made me guess something like that was happening. Thanks for detailing the causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View.inflate` imho is a not the clearest method ) it returns the root View of the inflated hierarchy. **If root was supplied, this is the root View**; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

So obj_item is not an item view. It is an items_list_layout view. Inside it you find `R.id.item_label` in first item view and set it. Other item views are not initialized because findViewById returns first item it found.

Change this part:

```
LinearLayout obj_item = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(view.getContext(), R.layout.item, items_list_layout);
```

to

```
LinearLayout obj_item = LayoutInflator.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, items_list_layout, false);
```

I prefer to add child views explicitly to make code more readable. So and add this code to add item view to parent layout:

```
items_list_layout.addView(obj_item)
```

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly. Thank you... I just had to change the `LayoutInflator` by `LayoutInflater` from your example ;-)