# Is it possible doing a "clickable item" by extending ConstraintLayout and loading in an specific XML, in order to apply polymorfism later?

Tags: java, android, xml

I was thinking on inflating XML objects from file, which is basically a `ConstraintLayout` with some TextViews inside. But by extending ConstraintLayout like this, and using this instead of ConstraintLayout:

```
public class CommonLayout extends ConstraintLayout {
    private TextView myTitle;
    private TextView myDesc;

    public CommonLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        loadWidgets();
    }

    public CommonLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        loadWidgets();
    }

    public CommonLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        loadWidgets();
    }

    public CommonLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        loadWidgets();
    }

    private void loadWidgets() {
        myTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.layoutTitle);
        myDesc = this.findViewById(R.id.layoutDesc);
    }

    // ----
    public void setMyTitle(String input) {
        myTitle.setText(input);
    }

    public void setMyDescription(String input) {
        myDesc.setText(input);
    }
}
```

It might seem weird that I want to extend the ConstraintLayout, I know... the big idea is that I can inflate those ConstraintLayout childrens (esentially a clone of ConstraintLayout with some methods that would find default TextViews inside XML "CommonLayout" files and set its text -In other words, isolate and encapsulate child views logic in the CommonLayout itself). If it works, then I will extend this with more ConstraintLayout children and a common interface to apply polimorfism.

**The whole point is load inflated "CommonLayout"s into some LinearLayout. And those "CommonLayout" would contain TextViews inside which I want to set dinamically, and those CommonLayout objects would always be inflated from `view_commonlayout.xml` file.** If this works, I want to escalate it with different ConstraintLayout children. "But why extending ConstraintLayout at all? Can't you just inflate normal `ConstraintLayout`s for this?" Well... maybe... but if I, for some reason, needed a common interface for all children, I could just add `implements I_SomeCommonInterface` to apply polimorfism right away if the situation requires it, by having ConstraintLayout extended... or that's the idea at least

...then, I want to use it like this more or less:

```
// ...from some fragment...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_fragment, container, false);

    // XXX The point is inflating CommonLayouts into this LinearLayout
    LinearLayout mainLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.theLinearLayout);

    //CommonLayout obj1 = new CommonLayout(getContext());
    CommonLayout obj1 = (CommonLayout) LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_commonlayout, mainLayout, false);

    obj1.setMyTitle("Good morning");
    obj1.setMyDescription(getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum));


    mainLayout.addView(obj1);

    return view;
}
```

I would like to load each CommonLayout from this XML `view_commonlayout.xml` file:

```
<com.mydomain.myapp.views.custom_widgets.CommonLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layoutTitle"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Here goes THE TITLE"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layoutDesc"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Here goes the description"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutTitle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

</com.mydomain.myapp.views.custom_widgets.CommonLayout>
```

¿What I am doing wrong to achieve what I am trying here? It will always fail with `NullPointerException` when using `setMyTitle` and `setMyDescription` (I started doing the first "domino stack test" of the whole thing right now and some other things could fail after solving the `NullpointerException`, but for now this is my first concern...)

At least, I know that, (by the TraceBack) `myTitle` variable is null. So, `this.findViewById()` is failing. Probably because I don't know exactly how to inflate from the XML file and keep it alltogether in the same class (obviously my `LayoutInflater.inflate(params)` attempt still makes it fail the same way than just using `new` operator). And I am stuck just right there...

#### Clarification:

The planned structure of views is not intended to load any kind of data, neither from DB neither from any User Preferences or anything. The intention is to make a "dynamic main menu" with this.

For now, if it works, I will fill it with just a few static options. But, in the future, I might make it a little dynamic depending on user's history of use of the app, for example. But for now, I'd be just glad if I could get this done with the planned structure or something similar to this structure I planned.

There's still a doubt that could make my idea useless. I was hoping that, if I inflate some XML file (like `view_commonlayout.xml`) I could assign it into the XML file's top parent type of variable (in this case CommonLayout) and from there access the children (the TextViews). And maybe, just maybe, encapsulate this XML structure's behaviour and everything related to itself within the `CommonLayout` class itself. (even though I am not sure about all the implementation details). **Some of these wild ideas might be unfeasible**, and if so, I will have to look for some workaround. Maybe I should try a different approach, like making a new "wrapper class" instead of extending ConstraintLayout?

#### The purpose

This whole thing is intended to add a new feature for my app already published in Google Play Store, something like a "dynamic landing menu" to attract user's attention to some of my app's most important features. I'd share the link but it's only available in my home country, and I am not sure if that would help clarifying the question at all.

It's like I would make several options with each common layout, with option title and option description. Each CommonLayout loaded would have its OnClickListener to open some menu, more or less. For now I am just glad with only one type of XML structure (the one inside `view_commonlayout.xml`), but in the future I'd like to feed in other XML structures with a ConstraintLayout-like parent, but different child views (instead of two TextViews, one ImageView and one TextView, for example; or maybe some mini-form to submit something... in which case I might need to extract a common interface to apply polimorfism (for example, having all a common interface with method `setOnClickListener` or `setLayoutTitle` or things like that...)).

#### `NullPointerException` solved

In the end, solving the `NullPointerException` was easier than I thought... I am not sure if the solution is elegant, but it worked. I just had to change the `CommonLayout` class a little, by getting rid of `loadWidgets` method and changing the setters like this:

```
public void setMyTitle(String input) {
    myTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.layoutTitle);
    myTitle.setText(input);
}

public void setMyDescription(String input) {
    myDesc = this.findViewById(R.id.layoutDesc);
    myDesc.setText(input);
}
```

Even though it solves the problem that made the App crash, it's too soon to self-answer the question. I still have to find out if I can make the inflated `CommonLayout` a button (probably it won't be that hard)... also, the whole point I wanted to extend ConstraintLayout is just I can force the children to implement an interface (which makes me considering editing this question's title)

Comment: To me it seems like an overkill, especially when Android offers DataBinding. You can have a layout (xml) file with fields for data (e.g, title, description) and bind to them in your Activity/Fragment. If you want an example I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @gioravered It's not for data; it's more like a "dynamic main menu", so using `LiveData<>` is non-sense here. But you have a point this might be overkill

Comment: I made, almost half year ago, [a question to a similar but different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72876545/3692177) which answer was useful for me. Maybe it will help the readers of this question (and also myself) as well to compare that previous problem with this one. The main difference is that I wasn't trying to encapsulate the behaviour in the previous question.

Comment: The "data" here is the title & description. I meant that you can create a layout (xml) file and use <include> tag to use it wherever you need. Then you can set the title and description inside the <include> tag using "tools:bind=" attribute.

Comment: @gioravered Even though it sounds interesting, and I have recently looked at [DataBinding's Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding), I still must insist to not consider Title and Description as "data" in that sense. Because if the objects work as planned, those properties will be filled with some static `string` resources, or, as much, as the result of some calculation. My main concern here is not how to bind the data, but rather how can I apply polimorfism to different subsets of XML ConstraintLayout based views.

Comment: @gioravered In other words, I am trying to do something similar to what I achieved in the question I shared before, **but self-contained in a dedicated class** that's only responsible for that XML View's structure and behaviour (if that class is a son of ConstraintLayout or just a wrapper class is not important, as long as i can isolate everything related to "inflate" the XML and setting its properties within the mentioned class; and that includes setting the child TextViews).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, you can extend ConstraintLayout, use the child within an XML resource file like a normal ConstraintLayout, and it seems everything behaves as you would expect from CostraintLayout.

I want to develop a more detailed answer from here about polymorfism advantages of this, but I need more time for that.